# Unable to setup static website on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

According to [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called /static in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext

I've set up `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**` in the `application.properties` - nonetheless I get an error 404.

(`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`)

---

Here is my project hierarchy:

[image: Project Hierarchy]

---

What am I missing?

**Solution:**

I had a Controller Mapping to `/`, after removing it I could see the website! *facepalm*

Comment: I don't get it - why have you set up `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**` when you should be using default configuration? You even quoted it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it without the `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**`? Or try to access `/static/index.html` with the property set? Because that setting changes where Spring Boot would look for static files, and I clearly see your `index.html` being in `resources/static` folder.